# SQL Server Reporting Services 2008: How to set the credentials property properly?

Tags: security, reporting-services

No matter how I configure the Credentials property I get a 401 exception when I try to Render the report.  Here is my (latest) code:

```
var rs = new ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Url = "https://myserver/reportserver/reportexecution2005.asmx";

        var myCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
        myCache.Add(new Uri(rs.Url), "kerberos" , new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "Domain"));

        rs.Credentials = myCache;
```

The URL and credentials are all correct.  But still getting a 401 when I cal rs.Render(...).  The Reporting Services install is sitting on a Windows Server 2008 box and requires integrated authentication.

Thanks

Comment: Also,  in the reportserver.config I'm using <RSWindowsBasic/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:
Modify my rsreportserver.config file so as to ONLY allow BASIC authentication.  I had both BASIC and KERBEROS allowed and it wasn't until I commented out all other allowable types *but* basic that things started to work.

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
             <RSWindowsBasic/>
      </AuthenticationTypes>
```

Not sure why this is (at least not totally).  But these links on msdn were helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx